# list wrongly appended after few iteration in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import copy

x_input = np.array([[ 0.0000000,    0.0000000,  0.0000000],
                    [ 0.7570000,    0.5860000,  0.0000000]])

x_input_ = np.array([[ 0.0000000,   0.0000000,  0.0000000],
                    [ 0.7570000,    0.5860000,  0.0000000]])

# x_input_ = copy.deepcopy(x_input)

delta = 0.1
xlist = []
for i in range(len(x_input)):
    for j in range(np.shape(x_input)[1]):
            print(i,j)
            print (x_input)
            x_input[i,j] = x_input[i,j] + delta
            print(x_input)
            xlist.append(x_input)
            print('xlist:')
            print(xlist)
            x_input = x_input_
print(xlist)
```

Question: why at i=0, j=2 iterartion the appended `xlist` is wrong? However at i=0,j=0 and i=0,j=1, the `xlist` is right.

Comment: the error comes from the ```x_input = x_input_ ``` line. why the value of x_input_ not assigned to x_input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list contains one reference to the array that was originally called `x_input`, and five more references to the array `x_input_` (with a trailing underscore).

If you want separate references each time, you probably want to be copying the array, rather than just referencing it repeatedly. I'm not exactly sure what output you expect.

If you want cumulative results, so that each successive array in the list is the previous array with an addition, change the `append` line to:

```
xlist.append(copy.deepcopy(x_input))
```

And get rid of the last line in the loop, where you rebind `x_input`.

If you instead want each array to have just one change from the original value (a different one for each), leave the append as it is, and instead change the last line of the loop to:

```
x_input = copy.deepcopy(x_input_)
```

Comment: I want each array to have just one change from the original values. so ```x_input = copy.deepcopy(x_input_)``` worked. Thank you!